# Visual Studio Cordova cannot build on android

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I got the following error at output when I build the code to android device.

```
1>------ Clean started: Project: Shhh...ItWorks, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
1>  Running: C:\app\TW Secret\11232015\Shhh...ItWorks_\Shhh...ItWorks\platforms\android\gradlew clean -b C:\app\TW Secret\11232015\Shhh...ItWorks_\Shhh...ItWorks\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
1>
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>  * What went wrong:
1>  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
1>  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
1>     > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+.
1>       Searched in the following locations:
1>           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml
1>           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/
1>       Required by:
1>           :android:unspecified
1>     > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+.
1>       Searched in the following locations:
1>           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
1>           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
1>       Required by:
1>           :android:unspecified
1>
1>  * Try:
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>
1>  BUILD FAILED
1>
1>  Total time: 2.267 secs
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
1>
1>  C:\app\TW Secret\11232015\Shhh...ItWorks_\Shhh...ItWorks\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c ""C:\app\TW Secret\11232015\Shhh...ItWorks_\Shhh...ItWorks\platforms\android\gradlew" clean -b "C:\app\TW Secret\11232015\Shhh...ItWorks_\Shhh...ItWorks\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(354,5): error MSB3073: The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 1.
========== Clean: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And when I tried to clean the solution it shows this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   MSB3073 The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 1.   Shhh...ItWorks  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
```

I'm using Cordova 5.3.3 
Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Hey, Does a simple 'blank' template project deploy successfully to your android device from VS? What about deploying to Ripple? Is it only the device that is broken? What version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

After removing and reinstalling plugins one by one, I found out it's the push plugin that is conflicting with the local notification plugin, remove one or another fix the problem : )